# The shape is not displayed on the form when I start working with threads(Window Forms)

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

where should I insert Graphics it to make the game work???

I want to develop a multithreaded application that simulates the movement of billiard balls on a gaming table. The behavior of each ball (i.e. calculating new coordinates and redrawing) is programmed as a separate thread. The usual physical laws apply on the game table - balls bounce off the walls and corners of the table so that the angle of incidence is equal to the angle of reflection, the only exception for this problem is the absence of interactions between the balls (i.e., simply put, they do not collide).
When starting the simulation process, each ball receives some (random) impulse, under the influence of which it moves by inertia, gradually stopping. When the ball stops, the corresponding flow should end. The application
makes sure that there is at least one thread that has not finished its work yet. When all the threads are completed, you need to issue the appropriate message. The program should provide the user with the ability to pause/continue or interrupt the motion simulation process.
To do this, I created everything that is above, and then I don't understand where to move a little

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<Circle> circles = new List<Circle>();
        private List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
        private bool pause = false;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void AddCircle()
        {
            Circle circle = new Circle();
            circles.Add(circle);

        }
 private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
                pause = !pause;
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = CreateGraphics();
            g.Clear(Color.White);
            foreach (Circle circle in circles)
                g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(circle.color), circle.X, circle.Y, circle.Weidth, circle.Heidth);
        }

        private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(t =>
            {
            AddCircle();
            Thread.Sleep(30);
            })
            { IsBackground = true };
            threads.Add(thread);
            thread.Start();
        }

        
    }
}
```

this is my class circle

```
 public class Circle
    {
        public float x;
        public float y;
        public float heidth;
        public float weidth;
        public float dy;
        public float dx;
        public Color color;
        public List<Color> colors = (new Color[] { Color.Pink, Color.Red, Color.Brown, Color.Black }).ToList();
        

        public float X
        {
            set { x = value; }
            get { return x; }
        }

        public float Y
        {
            set { y = value; }
            get { return y; }
        }

        public float Heidth
        {
            set { heidth = value; }
            get { return heidth; }
        }

        public float Weidth
        {
            set { weidth = value; }
            get { return weidth; }
        }

        public float Dy
        {
            set { dy = value; }
            get { return dy; }
        }

        public float Dx
        {
            set { dx = value; }
            get { return dx; }
        }

        public Color Color
        {
            set { color = value; }
            get { return color; }
        }

        public Circle()
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            x = random.Next(10, 600);
            y = random.Next(10, 500);
            color = colors[random.Next(colors.Count)];
            weidth = 10;
            heidth = 10;
            dx = random.Next(-50, 50);
            dy = random.Next(-50, 50);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First thing, remove this: `Graphics g = CreateGraphics();` from the `Paint` handler (`e.Graphics` is what you need). Then remove the Thread, replace with a Timer. Declare the `Random` object as a static Field and remove it from the Constructor.

Comment: Also if you are accessing `circles` from a different thread you need to `lock` it. Better idea: transform all of this to use `async` `await` or a `Timer`

Comment: Every thread you create uses a minimum of 1MB of memory. And you're doing that to only create a circle and add it to a list. The amount of CPU processing to create the thread and destroy it vastly outweighs the work that the thread does. You shouldn't use threads in this way.

Comment: Also, since you are expecting the UI to display the circles you have to do that on the UI thread. Displaying the circles uses vastly more CPU resources than creating and updating the location of the circles. There is no need to use threads for what you're doing.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by using threads?

Comment: Did you also know that `random.Next(-50, 50)` will generate a random number between `-50` and `49`?

Comment: @Jimi I can 't delete threads because I need to interact with them . I'll insert the timer a little later. At this stage, I need to display the balls by mouse click when launching the program. I realized that I draw my balls in paint, but I don't use graphics anywhere. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Enigmativity I have to use threads for the task.  I need to display the balls by mouse click when launching the program. I realized that I draw my balls in paint, but I don't use graphics anywhere. How can I fix this?

Comment: @lijooooooo - What do you mean by " I realized that I draw my balls in paint, but I don't use graphics anywhere. How can I fix this?"???

Comment: @lijooooooo - It seems to me that you only need a single background thread to meet the requirement of the assignment. The movement of the balls is key with this code.

Comment: @Enigmativity if I understand correctly, I don't need to create a new thread every time? but I need to display not one ball on the form, but many balls. one ball - one threads

Comment: Ideally you'd use a single thread - executed from a Timer that works on a background thread to update all of your balls.

Comment: You're not using *Graphics*? What is this: `Graphics g = CreateGraphics();`, in your view? What I said is: *remove `Graphics g = CreateGraphics();`*  (which is as bad as it gets) and *replace it with `e.Graphics`* (the Graphics object you must use in a `Paint` handler) -- You don't need a Thread **at all**.

Comment: @Jimi - It seems he needs to use (at least) a thread because the assignment said so.

Comment: @Enigmativity I didn't read the message directed to you. Not clear whether the assignment is: *build something that uses a Thread* or explicitly *draw something on a canvas using a Thread*. If the latter, I hope someone explained how safe is a `List<T>` in this context. Maybe someone explained the use of `ConcurrentQueue<T>` or `ConcurrentBag<T>` but it didn't make the cut in the sample code.

Comment: Re, "I have to use threads for the task. I need to display the balls by mouse click" You don't need a thread per ball in order to know whether the location of a mouse click coincides with the location of a ball. You only need to iterate over a list of balls within the click handler until you either find one (or not) that overlaps the location of the click.